# Location of pin is changing while zoom in/out in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation, location, pinchzoom

I'm facing an issue while zooming the map. The pin's location is changing when I zoom. I've used google_maps_flutter plugin. App's requirement is to select place and show pin. The pin is showing properly on the selected location but when I zoom, the pin's location is changing. I've not used marker here.
My code is given below.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildGoogleMap(context),
        _buildPin(),
        _buildMapIcons(context),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Here is the buildPin method

```
Widget _buildPin() {
    return Center(
      child: Selector<PlaceProvider, PinState>(
        selector: (_, provider) => provider.pinState,
        builder: (context, state, __) {
          if (pinBuilder == null) {
            return _defaultPinBuilder(context, state);
          } else {
            return Builder(
              builder: (builderContext) => pinBuilder!(builderContext, state),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

Widget _defaultPinBuilder(BuildContext context, PinState state) {
    if (state == PinState.Preparing) {
      return Container();
    } else if (state == PinState.Idle) {
      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/ic_custom_marker.png',
                    width: 180.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                  ),
                ), //assets/ic_location_pin.png
                const SizedBox(height: 42),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 5,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                AnimatedPin(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/ic_custom_marker.png',
                      width: 180.0,
                      height: 60.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ), //assets/ic_location_pin.png
                const SizedBox(height: 42),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 5,
              height: 5,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

 Widget _buildGoogleMap(BuildContext context) {
return GoogleMap(
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          compassEnabled: false,
          mapToolbarEnabled: false,
          initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
          mapType: data,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            provider.mapController = controller;
            provider.setCameraPosition(null);
            provider.pinState = PinState.Idle;
            // When select initialPosition set to true.
            if (selectInitialPosition!) {
              provider.setCameraPosition(initialCameraPosition);
              _searchByCameraLocation(provider);
            }
          },
          circles: context.read<LocationSelectionCubit>().circles,
          onCameraIdle: () {
            if (provider.isAutoCompleteSearching) {
              provider.isAutoCompleteSearching = false;
              provider.pinState = PinState.Idle;
              provider.placeSearchingState = SearchingState.Idle;
              return;
            }
            // Perform search only if the setting is to true.
            if (usePinPointingSearch!) {
              // Search current camera location only if camera has moved (dragged) before.
              printData(provider.cameraPosition!.target.longitude);
              provider.currentPosition = provider.currentPosition = Position(
                latitude: provider.cameraPosition!.target.latitude,
                longitude: provider.cameraPosition!.target.longitude,
                timestamp: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                  500,
                  isUtc: true,
                ),
                altitude: 3000.0,
                accuracy: 0.0,
                heading: 0.0,
                speed: 0.0,
                speedAccuracy: 0.0,
                isMocked: false,
              );
              provider.selectedPlace = null;

              context.read<LocationSelectionCubit>().getAllCircle();
              // context.read<LocationSelectionCubit>().drawCircles(provider.currentPosition!.latitude, provider.currentPosition!.longitude, radius)
              if (provider.pinState == PinState.Dragging) {

                // Cancel previous timer.
                if (provider.debounceTimer?.isActive ?? false) {
                  provider.debounceTimer!.cancel();
                }
                provider.debounceTimer =
                    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: debounceMilliseconds!), () {
                  _searchByCameraLocation(provider);
                });
              }
            }
            provider.pinState = PinState.Idle;
          },
          onCameraMoveStarted: () {
            provider.setPrevCameraPosition(provider.cameraPosition);

            // Cancel any other timer.
            provider.debounceTimer?.cancel();

            // Update state, dismiss keyboard and clear text.
            provider.pinState = PinState.Dragging;

            // Begins the search state if the hide details is enabled
            if (hidePlaceDetailsWhenDraggingPin!) {
              provider.placeSearchingState = SearchingState.Searching;
            }

            onMoveStart!();
          },
          onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
            provider.setCameraPosition(position);
          },
          // gestureRecognizers make it possible to navigate the map when it's a
          // child in a scroll view e.g ListView, SingleChildScrollView...
          gestureRecognizers: Set()
            ..add(
              Factory<EagerGestureRecognizer>(
                () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
              ),
            ),
        );
}
```

Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What's the reason you are not using markers? Does using markers also fixes the issue?